# I am trying to install Haskell using Chocolatey and had an 'error while running C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\cabal\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'

Tags: powershell, haskell, installation, chocolatey

I have to use Haskell for an upcoming class and I'm trying to install it on my device using Chocolatey.

I used the command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; 
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

to install Chocolatey which went smoothly.

Then I did "`choco install haskell-dev`"

That's when I got this error: text in PowerShell saying

```
"ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Olivia' because it does not exist.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
The install of cabal was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\cabal\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details."
```

[image]
I only tried to download and install the packages, I didn't do much troubleshooting other than that just because I don't know where to go from here. I'm tempted to just continue on and see if it'll work but I don't want it to be broken then have to work back to this.

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question and append the error text as **text**

Comment: Are you obligated to use Chocolatey? The most common way to install haskell is via `ghcup`. Please check the [official](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/) documentation for more info